# Why am I getting "NoReverseMatch at /" error?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, renderer

I am getting the next NoReverseMatch error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.11.3
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Exception Location:     /home/ivan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.12
Python Path:    

['/home/ivan/My_website/essostrade (copy 1)',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/ivan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']

Server time:    Fri, 25 Aug 2017 22:51:14 +0000
```

[image]

But the thing is that there is no 'logout' neither in the highlighted main.js line in the template, nor somewhere else in the templates.

Here are my templates:
main.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block additional_css %}
  <link type="text/css" href="{% static "main.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Браавосская лавочка</h1>
  </div>
 <!-- <div id="leftmenu">
    <ul>
      {% url "main" as page_url %}
      <li><a href="{{ page_url }}"{% if page_url == current_url %} class="current"{% endif %}>Главная</a></li>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="indented"><a href="/admin/">Админка</a></li>
        <li class="indented"><a href="{% url "logout" %}">Выйти</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul> 
  </div>   -->       
<div id="main">
  {% block main %}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>Все права принадлежат Матери Драконов</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

mainpage.html:

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% block title %}Главная страница{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
  <h2>Удивительные товары со всего Вестероса</h2>
  <p>Фирма веников не вяжет, фирма делает гробы</p>
{% endblock %}
```

here is my views.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from generic.mixins import CategoryListMixin
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django import forms





class MainPageView(TemplateView, CategoryListMixin):
    template_name = "mainpage.html"





class LoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "login_logout.html"
    isLoggedIn = False





class PageNumberMixin(CategoryListMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PageNumberMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context["pn"] =  self.request.GET["page"]
        except KeyError: 
            context["pn"] = "1"
        return context  





def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

And here is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static  import static
from django.conf.urls import include
from main.views import LoginView, MainPageView
from main.views import signup

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', MainPageView.as_view(), name='main'),
    url(r'^signup/$', signup, name='signup'),



]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I really don't know where did this 'logout' appear from.

Comment: Note that Django has a [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView). It would be better to use this instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.html` template is trying to reverse the URL logout, but you haven't added a URL pattern for the logout view.

```
{% url "logout" %}

from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
```

You'll have to either create a `registration/logged_out.html` template to display, or set `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` in your settings.

Comment: But        `{% url "logout" %}`     is commented out. How can it cause any errors?

Comment: `<!--` is an html comment. Django will still try to render its contents. For multiline comments in Django you need the [`{% comment %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#comment) tag.

Comment: thanx. This is a very important info I previously didn't know about Django. So if I want to comment it as both html and Django, I need something like `<!-- {% comment % } {% comment % } -->`

Comment: The contents of the `{% comment %}` tag won't appear in the rendered html, so there is no need to wrap it in `<!--`